# Domain name change but search for <new-name> doesn't show

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, marketing

I've moved a our domain from oldname.com to newdomain.com 35days ago. newname is a relatively unique word, and still for some reason searches for newname doesn't show up in search results. Instead articles about the name change appear in the first page.

I assumed this should just take a bit of time, but 35 days seems too much. Is this to be expected?

In GWT I can see google is still crawling mainly my old website (I guess looking for all the 301 redirects?).

New website WMT crawls:
[image]

Old website WMT crawls:
[image]

Comment: Is your new domain indexed?

Comment: Large scale changes- especially domain name changes- will take months to settle out.

Comment: @closetnoc so you'd say this makes sense for now? does the old domain high crawl rate also seem fine?

Comment: Without any real data to back this up, I find this to take a bit long. Yes it takes time, but IMO you should see something by now. Though crawling should not be your main concern, visitors per day are ;)

Comment: @Martijn visitors per day is actually fine (long tail traffic). not sure why the homepage isn't showing up and if this might be a red-flag to a problem

Comment: Nothing happens within 30 days with Google. Domain name changes are the most disruptive thing you can do. It will take time to fetch all the pages, index the pages, recalculate the index scores, recalculate the SERP performance metrics, recalculate link values, recalculate the domain trust metrics, etc. You just jerked a major knot in Googles tail and you expect a 30 day response time? Do you know how large the web is? Do you know how large the Google index is? It is also distributed- and you want your data everywhere? Not happening in 30 days.

Comment: Without specifics you are asking us to guess. The domain name(s) and the keyword you are talking about will help us to determine what is going on. Otherwise, how could we possibly know if you have a problem or not??

Comment: @closetnoc Sure. twtrland.com is the old name, klear.com is the new name. Didn't want to self promote. Keywords are "twtrland" and "Klear"

Comment: The term *klear* is highly(!) competitive and you just arrived on the scene! You have a new domain name now. The value of the old domain name is largely gone and you are starting over. This is why I do not recommend domain name changes. Even then, you are on the first page of Google.com (from here anyway) so be happy with that. It will just plain take a while.

Comment: @closetnoc odd, here it doesn't show in first page. Also klear.me is appearing first (doesn't seem to be a tough competitor) and news articles about the rebranding are also there, which I should assume must rank below the actual site. Which competitors do you see that are highly competitive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26580/discussion-between-noam-and-closetnoc).

Comment: It is not the sites that are competitive, it is the term that is competitive. Keep in mind, **you are starting over** and are competing with everyone who has ever used this term who has been around for a while including a company/product brand name. You are the new kid on the block as far as this term is concerned. Good and proper SEO and time should give you what you want.